# Ajuda para montar select no banco

Tags: jquery, mysql, html5, apache-cordova

Olá, eu estou precisando montar uma query no banco que me retorne um conjunto de registros mas como não tenho tanta experiência em banco de dados gostaria que vocês me dessem uma ajuda. É o seguinte: Tenho as tabelas

**tb_partida**(*id, flag_ativa, flag_cancelado, flag_finalizado, data_hora, time_casa_gols, time_fora_gols, tb_id_cotacao, tb_campeonato_id*);

**tb_partida_time**(*tb_partida_id, tb_time_id, ordem*);

**tb_time**(*id, nome_time, tb_campeonato_id*);

**tb_cotacao**(*id, casa, empate, fora, gol_meio, mais_2gm, menos_3gm, ambas_marcam, casa_empate, fora_empate, casa_marca, fora_marca, casa_ou_fora, casavence_foramarca, foravence_casamarca, casavence_zero, foravence_zero*)

**tb_campeonato**(*id, nome_camp, tb_pais_id*).

No meu app eu preciso montar, para cada no meu banco, um HTML que mostre uma tabela com os times da partida, a data/hora e as cotações. Preciso construir uma tabela para cada partida do campeonato que vai ter todos esses dados. Alguém pode me ajudar à fazer essa query?

[image: App]

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar uma tabela para guardar os registros e a usar como referência ? Criar uma tabela para cada partida é realmente necessário ?

Comment: Quis dizer que preciso montar um tabela HTML com os registros. Como a tabela da foto.

Comment: Então você quer o select e a tabela em HTML?

Comment: Será o resultado final mas eu preciso de ajuda somente com o select.